# Spark: Merge columns of the same dataframe without creating additional dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following data frame

```
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|                uid2|               uid1|    timestamp|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|a                   |b                  |1589505008851|
|c                   |d                  |1589505012502|
|e                   |f                  |1589505016153|
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

and I want to create something like that

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|                uids|          timestamp|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|a                   |1589505008851      |
|c                   |1589505012502      |
|e                   |1589505016153      |
|b                   |1589505008851      |
|d                   |1589505012502      |
|f                   |1589505016153      |
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

so I would like to merge the `uid1` and `uid2` columns into one column. The columns have the exact same length and they are of the same data type. Can I do this without creating an additional dataframe and "unioning" the two? Just by referencing the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `explode / array` -approach :

```
df
.select(explode(array($"uid1",$"uid2")).as("uids"),$"timestamp")
.show()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! I will accept the answer in 2 minutes.. Apparently there is a limit to this...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by:

Generating sample data

```
val data = Seq(("a", "b","1589505008851"), ("c", "d","1589505008852"), ("e", "f","1589505008854"))

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

var df = rdd.toDF("uid2","uid1","timestamp")
```

Code which will transform the data as per your requirement.

```
df=df.select($"uid2".as("uids"),$"timestamp").union(df.select($"uid1".as("uids"),$"timestamp"))
```